# Post to page wall from my website (with "Hide from News Feed")

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

It's possible to manually add a post to my wall for past and check "Hide from News Feed", but is there any way to post to my wall with "Hide from News Feed" option from my website with PHP?

Answer (score 4):

By looking at the [Graph API documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/), you can see that there is no such option for a Post. Moreover, if you retrieve a news feed from the Graph API, posts that were hidden are not present in the returned json. You can try it by querying the Grap API about your news feed, hide a post and query it again. If you compare the two jsons you will see that the hidden post is just not present in the second. So I would say that it is not possible.